# In MVVM, should model objects be accessible by the view via a ObservableCollection<TModelObject> object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Say I have a collection of `PersonModel` class objects (obviously located within the model of my app):

```
List<PersonModel> People { get;set; }
```

What is the appropriate way to consume this object within my app's view, but as a `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Do I need to create a `PersonViewModel` class within the `ViewModel`, and then copy the contents of each `PersonModel` object to a new `PersonViewModel` object, **AND THEN** insert each of these `PersonViewModel` objects into a `ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel>` object?

I ask because with my limited knowledge so far, it doesn't seem to make sense for a view to even be able to **SNIFF** a model object:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{MY List<PersonModel> OBJECT}" />
```

Is that considered to be appropriate? Seems like the `ListView` should only know about `PersonViewModel` objects. Thanks!

Comment: MVVM is a paradigm not a set of handcuffs. You are right that model objects (even view model objects) should not know about view objects, at all. Beyond that, there are arguments pro and con for being rigid about wrapping model objects in view model objects 100% of the time. It's a matter of opinion as to whether it's legitimate to forego a view model object when a regular model object will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

MVVM is just separation of concerns. It is perfectly valid of view to be aware of what viewmodel has to offer - that is the foundation for bindings! So make use of those bindings:

```
// Use of appropriate observable types - in collections
// ObservableCollection is the type you should use, as it notifies UI layers
// about collection changes. It implements INotifyPropertyChanged
ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People { get;set; }
```

If you use any object to bind to its properties, make it also "observable" by implementing `INotifyPropertyChnaged` interface. So there you should use `PersonViewModel`, which should implement said interafce (you can think of it as a small sub-viewmodel).

Then you are set to use it in view by binding:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}" />
```

**REMARK**

It's better to use readonly fields for collections and only add/remove items, so:

```
ObservableCollection<PersonModel> People { get; } = new ObservableCollection<PersonModel>();
```

Comment: TC immediately wrote that his question was not about collection type. He himself understands the differences between List and ObservableCollection.
His question relates to the implementation of the elements of this collection: In what cases it is permissible to use a type from the Model (PersonModel), and in what cases you need an additional type of the ViewModel level (PersonViewModel).

Comment: @EldHasp I think I covered all aspects with my edit :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Thanks for the reply. So, if it is okay for the View to use a ObservableCollection<PersonModel> object directly, then why do so many people make a big deal of wrapping PersonModel objects in a PersonViewModel object? So, then, the view only sees and binds to the ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> object...

Answer (score -2):

This is very specific to each problem being solved.
In general, application layers exchange immutable data with each other to avoid parasitic dependencies.

In this case, your PersonModel type will be immutable.
And if in the Window you only need to display it without the possibility of editing (changing properties), then it will be enough to use PersonModel.
If you need some additional functions in the GUI (new properties, mutability, etc.), then you will have to create an additional type.

And it is not necessary to rewrite all values ​​from PersonModel in PersonViewModel.
You can simply make a property on the PersonViewModel that will hold the PersonModel instance.

Using an ObservableCollection lets the View "know" that the collection has changed.
If the collection is dynamic, that is, elements are removed/added/replaced in it in realtime, then the correct operation of bindings and ItemsControl without ObservableCollection (INotifyCollectionChanged) or IBindingList cannot be implemented.
If the collection is static and is always replaced only in its entirety or is set once when the collection is changed, then even the List is redundant.
Better to use IEnumerable or IEnumerable<T>.